# Quotient Map With Singleton Fibers has Hausdorff Codomian

Tags: general-topology

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a quotient map such that $|f^{- 1}(y)| = 1$ for all $y \in Y - \{y_0\}$, and $|f^{- 1}(y_0)| < \infty$. Prove that if $X$ is Hausdorff, so is $Y$.

I assume that I am supposed to use a contradiction but I got caught up with the $y_0$ case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you notice that $X-f^{-1}(y_0)$ is homeomorphic to $Y-\{y_0\}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $A=f^{-1}[\{y_0\}]$; then $Y$ is simply the result of identifying the finite set $A$ to a point, so for the most part $Y$ ‘looks like’ $X$; this may be helpful in getting a handle on what’s going on.

Let $A=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and let $y=f(x)\in Y\setminus\{y_0\}$. $X$ is Hausdorff, so there are open sets $U_k$ and $V_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ such that $x_k\in U_k$, $x\in V_k$, and $U_k\cap V_k=\varnothing$. Let $U=\bigcup_{k=1}^nU_k$ and $V=\bigcap_{k=1}^nV_k$, and consider the sets $f[U]$ and $f[V]$.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, thank you very much

Comment: @fluentsandfluxions: You’re very welcome.